# The best way to store sortable list in PostreSQL and Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a model A which has many B. So `a.bs` is a list of B. I want this list to be ordered by user. The common way is special order field in the database and then `:order_by => order_field` for B. But i don't want to manually manipulate with this field. Is there any special type in PostreSQL? Or maybe there is some extension or i can do this with trigger.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is kind of vague. Sure you can sort using order by `a.bs.order('order_field')`. By ordered by user mean you want the user to be able to change the sort? If that's the case check out [this gem](https://github.com/spullen/sort_this)

Comment: It would be better if you used examples from the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @spullen, think about the a.bs like about a table. Each row is B representation. I want be able to move rows up and down manually on my site page and then save this new ordering in the database.
The gem isn't a good idea because it doesn't use database server features, just some ruby code.

Comment: The gem does, it takes a configuration for different types of sorts then boils them down to sort queries (i.e. order clauses that you can change the direction on). So `sort_this :order_field => {}` in your `A` model it will allow you to do `A.sort(:order_field, 'ASC')` which produces => `SELECT * FROM as ORDER BY as.order_field ASC`

Comment: @spullen i'm thinking about special datatype, index or trigger. Order by is common solution for every SQL database.

Comment: You'll need to use the ORDER BY clause, but if you want to keep track of position try the [acts_as_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) gem

Comment: @spullen "The class that has this specified needs to have a position column defined as an integer". So it just uses simple integer field to do this. Even without INDEX. It's very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to store this stuff with some kind of order field, and you'll need to manipulate it manually...

It doesn't necessarily need to contain an integer, btw. For small numbers of values, a float works fine too -- that's what Postgres does in the pg_catalog when you alter an enum field and add a value before an existing one.

Comment: Hm. Float really good idea because i can just do something like SET order_field = (prev.order_field + next.order_field) / 2. But i think float indexes are rather slow.

Comment: Also i can't believe that there are no native postgresql function for this if pg_catalog works just this way.

Comment: The way the enums work is, if the values' order fields are zero, then order by oid, else sort by the order fields. If there are built-in routines, they're buried in the C code and (to the best of my knowledge) not available as SQL functions. The performance difference between the float index vs an integer index towards a table full of dead tuples is probably too negligible for you to be worrying about it.

Comment: Thanks, so seems like something like the best solution is
CREATE INDEX order_index ON test2 (a_id, order_field);
Also can you say what is "dead tuples". Can't find explanation in google.

Comment: Don't bother with an index at all on the `order_index` field, if it's tied to your A-B relationships (which is likely) rather than to your Bs. The joins with A and B will typically be selective enough that the ordering index will never get used anyway. Plus, it'll unlikely be relevant to be extracted at the db levels (this is one of those rare cases where ruby should be doing the sorting directly; especially for tags, categories, etc. where it's typically used). Re the dead tuples, you'd want to read up on MVCC: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/MVCC